# Microsoft Word 2007 remove the Autocorrect "formatting guide lines" for tables

Tags: microsoft-word, autocorrect

I'm using Microsoft Word 2007.
I wanted to removed the Autocorrect  "formatting guide lines" ( for lack of a better term ) for tables  that show up as you edit the document.
I've already Unchecked the border lines option in the Auto correct options:
[image]

However, the Autocorrect  "formatting guide lines" ( for lack of a better term ) for tables  still show up:

[image]

Could someone please tell me what steps I have to take to remove the Autocorrect  "formatting guide lines" ( for lack of a better term ) for tables ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft features can be silly sometimes.  I had to toggle the "View Gridlines" button.  please see below

[image]